# Change screen size of Genymotion programatically

Tags: android, genymotion

There's a chance to change the screen size and density of an already created genymotion machine by going to the machine on the genymotion launcher-> configure-> Screen size - Density.

I'd like to do this through a shell command, does this command exist? How can it be called if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it is not possible.
But we will soon release features related to continuous integration and automation. A command line tool will be included on these features. It allows you to do all what you can do with your mouse, but through the command line. And it will be available to paid licenses.

Editing the screen size and resolution is part of it.
Here is a demo we gave [at Droidcon Paris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFIz6I5nzXo#t=378)